# Asynchronous batch logging using Nlog and Asp.net core 2.0 in database

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, nlog

I am using NLog for logging in asp.net core 2.0. I am storing my log events in database.

I want my messages to save in batches asynchronously.

Nlog.config settings are:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true" 
internalLogLevel="Warn" internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" queueLimit="5000" batchSize="5" overflowAction="Discard">
       <target name="db" xsi:type="Database"
connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=userId;Password=pwd;"
commandType="StoredProcedure" commandText="Sp_name" dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient">
          <parameter name="@TimeStamp" layout="${date}" />
          <parameter name="@Level" layout="${uppercase:${level}}" />
          <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
          <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception}" />
          <parameter name="@StackTrace" layout="${exception:format=StackTrace,Data:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10}" />
      <parameter name="@eventLookupId" layout ="1" />
       </target>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
     <logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="" final="true" />
     <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
  </nlog>
```

For the above configuration I am expecting it to log in a batch size of 5 but it is logging immediately at the trigger of event rather than logging in a batch.

Not sure if any other configuration is also required to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

NLog will sent the messages continuously with of max of the batchsize (5 here), and with a time between batches. The default "timeToSleepBetweenBatches" for the asyncWrapper is 1 ms.

e.g. when the batchsize is 100 and the timeToSleepBetweenBatches is 1 sec, a max of 6000 messages/minute are sent.

See the options: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AsyncWrapper-target#buffering-options